# React-native Detecting the first successful fetch

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, react-native

in React-Native I have a bunch of IPs that I try to fetch simultaneously. The first one to answer with a specific status code is the one I am looking for. This part happens at the app startup, so it needs to be as fast as possible. Using the `async` library, my code is like this:

```
// Here an array with a bunch of IPs 
// ...

async.detect(uris, function(uri, callback) {
  // Fetching a specific URL associated with the IP
  fetch(`http://${uri}/productionservice/DataService.svc/`)
  .then((response) => {

  // If the URL answers with a 401 status code I know it's the one I'm looking for
  if(response.status == '401') {
    callback(null, true);
  // Otherwise It's not
  } else {
    callback(null, false)
  }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    callback(null, false)
  });
}, function(err, result) {

    if(typeof(result)=='undefined') {
      console.log('No result found');
    }
    console.log(result);
});
}
```

However, when one of the tests succeeds, I do get a result, but when none succeeds, the `detect` method hangs indefinitely, never letting me know that none of the IPs is returning the answer I expect.

My question is: How, using `async.detect` and RN's `fetch`, can I fetch multiple links, get a result if my test succeeds, or a `false` statement if none of them succeeds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using async await you can do something along these lines:

```
async function detect(uris) {
  const promises = [];
  uris.forEach((uri) => promises.push(fetch(`http://${uri}/productionservice/DataService.svc/`)));
  const responses = await Promise.all(promises);
  for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    if (responses[i] && responses[i].status === '401') {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It seems the `responses[i]` is returning the IP, not the response, thus the function infallibly returns `false`. What's more how do I handle the `Unhandled promise rejection` warnings? They keep popping up.

Comment: Wrap it in a try, and ignore the catch.

Comment: The responses should be the results of the fetch for each uri, that's not what you get?

Comment: Logging the `responses[i]` at each iteration, I only get the IPs that I passed, not the response of the `fetch`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It should be await Promise.all(promises)

Comment: Apologies, I saw your comment right this instant. And yes, it worked. Many thanks.